# Why my collection view disappear when updating the stepper value?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uistepper

here is my simplified code in my view controller

```
 class WishListVC: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var wishListCollectionView: UICollectionView!

        private var products = [Product]()
        private var selectedProduct : Product?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }



    //MARK: - cell Delegate
  extension WishListVC : ListProductCellDelegate {

     func addToCartButtonDidTapped(at selectedIndexPath: IndexPath, collectionView: UICollectionView) {

        guard let userOrder = userOrder else {return}
        let selectedProduct = products[selectedIndexPath.item]

        Order.addProductToOrderRealmDatabase(userOrder: userOrder, selectedProduct: selectedProduct)
        wishListCollectionView.reloadData()
        updateBadgeOnCartTabBar()


    }

        func stepperButtonDidTapped(at selectedIndexPath: IndexPath, stepperValue: Int, collectionView: UICollectionView) {

            guard let userOrder = userOrder else {return}
            let selectedProduct = products[selectedIndexPath.item]

            if stepperValue > 0 {
                Product.changeProductQuantityInRealmDatabase(selectedProduct: selectedProduct, quantity: stepperValue)
            } else {
                Order.removeProductFromOrderRealmDatabase(userOrder: userOrder, selectedProduct: selectedProduct)
                Product.changeProductQuantityInRealmDatabase(selectedProduct: selectedProduct, quantity: 0)
            }

            wishListCollectionView.reloadData()

            updateBadgeOnCartTabBar()

        }


    }

    //MARK: - Collection View Data Source 
    extension WishListVC : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return products.count
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: WishListStoryboardData.CollectionViewIdentifiers.productSliderCell.rawValue, for: indexPath) as? ListProductCell else { return UICollectionViewCell()}


            cell.productData = products[indexPath.item]
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.collectionView = wishListCollectionView



            return cell
        }

    }
```

and here is the code for my collection view cell:

```
protocol ListProductCellDelegate {
    func addToCartButtonDidTapped(at selectedIndexPath: IndexPath, collectionView : UICollectionView)
    func stepperButtonDidTapped( at selectedIndexPath: IndexPath, stepperValue: Int, collectionView : UICollectionView)
}

class ListProductCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var productImageViewAspectRatio: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var addToCartButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: GMStepper!

    var collectionView : UICollectionView?
    var delegate: ListProductCellDelegate?

    var productData : Product? {
        didSet {
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addToCartButtonDidPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {return}
        guard let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForView(view: sender) else {return}
        self.delegate?.addToCartButtonDidTapped(at: selectedIndexPath, collectionView: collectionView)
    }

    @IBAction func stepperDidTapped(_ sender: GMStepper) {
        guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else {return}
        guard let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForView(view: sender) else {return}
        self.delegate?.stepperButtonDidTapped(at: selectedIndexPath, stepperValue: Int(sender.value), collectionView: collectionView)
    }

    private func updateUI() {
        guard let product = productData else {return}

        stepper.value = Double(product.quantity)

        setLikeButton(product: product)
        setCartAndStepperButton()
    }


    private func setCartAndStepperButton() {

        guard let selectedProduct = productData else {return}

        func showStepperButton(status: Bool) {
            // to decide whether to show stepper or add to cart button.

            stepper.isHidden = !status
            stepper.isEnabled = status

            addToCartButton.isHidden = status
            addToCartButton.isEnabled = !status

        }

        if selectedProduct.quantity == 0 {
            showStepperButton(status: false)
        } else {
            showStepperButton(status: true)
        }


    }


}
```

I don't understand why after I tap the stepper for the first time after the 'Add To Cart' disappear, the collection view will disappear.

I don't have `collectionView.isHidden` in my entire code, but I don't know why my collection view disappear like the file .gif below

http://g.recordit.co/NAEc36MbrM.gif

but if the stepper is already show with some stepper value more than 1, then it will make my collection view dissapear like the gif below

http://recordit.co/SLdqf1ztFZ.gif

the minimum stepper value is set to be 1.

If I change the collection view reload data `wishListCollectionView.reloadData()` in the `stepperButtonDidTapped` method above to be just reload data in certain cell only using `wishListCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [selectedIndexPath])` the problem will be solved, but the stepper value seems it will be updated little slower, and it looks laggy.

I don't know how to trace the last line that will be executed so it makes my collection view disappears.

and if I reload the data in the main thread using:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.wishListCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
```

it won't make the collection view disappear, but If I edit the cell index 4 it will affect the cell index 1 like gif here: http://g.recordit.co/6802BJDdtx.gif

I change the number in the fifth cell but it will automatically change the second cell.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint at 'stepperButtonDidTapped' delegate method and check the count of 'products' array right before you reload your CV and check if the array is empty?

Comment: @LokSN no it is not empty

Comment: What about the items count at the 'numberOfItems' delegate method when you reload?

Answer (score 0):

Note to:

- Use Xcode Ui Debugging tool and check if your collectionView is hidden or empty
- Realm is realTime database ,any changes you make in database will be applied
  on your arrays too(like `products` array)

The reason of stepper problem is becouse of :

```
 guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: WishListStoryboardData.CollectionViewIdentifiers.productSliderCell.rawValue, for: indexPath) as? ListProductCell else { return UICollectionViewCell()}
```

and your using `stepperButtonDidTapped` delegete inside of cell.
declure your cells once and store them inside array,like below:

```
var cellArray:[ListProductCell]=[]
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if (cellArray.count > indexPath.row){
        return cellArray[indexPath.row]
    }else{
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: WishListStoryboardData.CollectionViewIdentifiers.productSliderCell.rawValue, for: indexPath) as? ListProductCell else { return UICollectionViewCell()}
        cell.productData = products[indexPath.item]
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.collectionView = wishListCollectionView
        cellArray.append(cell)
        return cell
    }}
```

Comment: unfortunately the stepper value is not zero :( , I can see in realm browser that the value is updated correctly but i don't know why the collection view dissapear. what makes it weird is because it can work if I use reload at only at certain cell using wishListCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [selectedIndexPath]) , but it seems laggy if I use that method

Comment: and my collection view is not hidden after I check :(

Comment: @Sarah what if you put  ` wishListCollectionView.reloadData()` in main Thread?

Comment: thanks for the response. using DispatchQue.main.async right? I just put that on my question above. yes you are right, it won't make the collection view dissapear, but If I edit the cell index 4 it will affect the cell index 1 like gif here: http://g.recordit.co/6802BJDdtx.gif I change the number in the fifth cell but it will automatically change the second cell.

Comment: your welcome,i updated the answer for you ,check it out @Sarah

Answer (score 0):

My case load get data success but not see data when reload.

This problem case born set **`Height`** in `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize` is **less than height cell** on **storyboard**.